# How to get the formatted value of a textbox

Tags: jquery, html

I have a textbox (`#price`) which converts a number into currency format on `focus` and `blur`:

```
$('#price').blur(function() {
        if ($('#price').val().length > 0) {
            $('#price').formatCurrency();
        }
    });

    $("#price").focus(function(){
        if ($('#price').val().length > 0) {
            $('#price').formatCurrency();
        }
    });
```

When I click a button on the form it should convert the value in the `#price` textbox if it is not already converted to the currency format and here is the handler for the button click (`#addToTable`):

```
$("#addToTable").click(function() {
        i++;
        var newPrice;
        var priceText = $("#spanPrice").text();
        var toRemove = 'Each: ';
        var priceEach = priceText.replace(toRemove,'');
        var rowId = "itemEntry" + i + "";
        if ($("#price").val().indexOf('.') == -1) {
            newPrice = $("#price").formatCurrency();
            alert(newPrice);
        }
        else {
            newPrice = $("#price").val();
            alert(newPrice+" 1");
        }
        var strRowEntry = '<tr id="itemEntry' + i + '"><td class="rowItem">' + $("#itemChoice option:selected").text() +'</td><td class="rowItem">' + priceEach + '</td><td class="rowItem">' + $("#quantity").val() + '</td><td class="rowItem">' + newPrice + '</td><td class="rowItem"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doThis(' + rowId + ');"><img class="deleteRow" src="edit.png" border="0" id="imgEdit" /></a></td></tr>';
        $('#tblItems tr:last').after(strRowEntry);
        $("#modalNew").hide();
        $('#modalNew').find('input:text').val('');
        $('#modalNew').find('span').text('Each: $9.00');
        $('#modalNew').find('SELECT').val('Wine');
    });
```

I check to see if the textbox is already converted into a currency format in the `if` statement, if it wasn't already converted, convert to currency. And the `else` statement just gets the value if the number is already converted.

The `else` statement works fine but the `if` statement displays `[object Object]`

How do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `formatCurrency()` does not return the formatted value, it will format text in the text box. so if you want to access the formatted value then you have to use `val()` on the textbox.

```
$("#price").formatCurrency();
newPrice = $("#price").val();
alert(newPrice);
```

Comment: yes, but calling focus is not right. because it will move focus to that text field which is a bad user experiance.

Comment: I close the pop up which displays the textbox as soon as the button is clicked so the end-user never sees it happening. I did UPVOTE your answer for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

In case other people run into the same issue, I had to set the focus on the `#price` textbox and then get the value.

```
if ($("#price").val().indexOf('.') == -1) {
            $("#price").focus();
            newPrice = $("#price").val();
            console.log(newPrice);
            alert(newPrice);
        }
```